# Does a Settlement Hierarchy plugin exists for QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, plugins

Is there a Settlement Hierarchy plugin for QGIS ? When I say settlement hierarchy I mean like a plugin that would designate where a village area begin and end ? Same with towns. So you could separate towns from villages from hamlets and isolated dwellings. Here is more information about settlement hierarchy : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Settlement_hierarchy